# Efficient way to check if username/email already exist in MongoDB for registration

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm in a `NodeJS` server using `ExpressJS` to handle my `/register` route. One step in my registration process is to ensure that the user's **username** and **email** are both unique, if so, they can register and add their account to the users collection.

Currently, my code is as follows for this "checking if username/email exists" step:

```
// Checking is user already exists (username & email)
try {
    const usernameExists = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if (usernameExists && emailExists) return res.status(400).send("Username and email already taken");
    if (emailExists) return res.status(400).send("Email already taken");
    if (usernameExists) return res.status(400).send("Username already taken");
} catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).send("Error querying DB to check if username/email exists or not");
}
```

This feels highly inefficient as I'm doing two queries to the database. Is there anyway to combine the two `User.findOne...` queries? Or is this how this task is supposed to be done?

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you want to check for both username and email to be unique, generally speaking this is how it is supposed to be done. I would suggest trimming the username and email values and convert to lowercase though. Right now you could have 2 seperate users with `Tom` and `tom` as username and `tom@gmail.com` and `Tom@gmail.com` as an email. Which will cause problems.

Comment: @Reinier68 Awesome, that makes sense! Slightly above the snippet I included, I have something similar to this: (`const username = req.body.username.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase();`).

Answer (score 2):

You can check for unique values in schema itself, just add unique in schema for the field you want. Like this

```
email:{
   unique:true,
   required:true,
},
username:{
   unique:true,
   required:true,
}
```

Comment: this looks great, so I added it to my Mongoose schema. It works for my username (forces it to be unique), however, it still allows my email field to have duplicates. Is there a limit to the number of unique fields in a schema you can have?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$or`

```
await User.findOne({
  $or: [{ username: req.body.username }, { email: req.body.email }],
})
```

Comment: Would I then be able to tell the user definitively with this single query if their selected username is taken or not, and/or if they're selected email is taken? Because, it would be possible for them to pick a username that belongs to account A, and an email that belongs to account B. Then, this would return the first of those 2 accounts that the query happens to find first, and I'd check the return to see if said user object has a conflicting email/username and only 1 would conflict - then I'd only be able to tell the user 1 error upon their submission even if both of their fields conflict

Comment: let me know if I'm wrong, I could be!